# How to support 1 Million or more WebSocket Connections using ASP.NET Core SignalR

Tags: websocket, signalr, real-time

I have been exploring SignalR, and am interested in learning how to build applications that support 1 Million or more connections. My first use case would be a real time multiplayer game with paired clients (1 player vs 1 player).

I was very excited to see Azure SignalR Service, but the service only supports a maximum of 100 units. With a max of 1000 connections per unit, that only comes to 100 000 connections.

Is there any architecture or technology that allows ASP.NET Core SignalR to support 1 million or more connections?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question. At this time the skus listed in the [pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/signalr-service/) don't go beyond that 100k max, but we have had this question with increasing frequency and are evaluating the various scenarios, of which there are a multitude of classes.

To be clear are you thinking you'd need 1,000,000 simultaneous connections? Or messages?

We plan on releasing guidance on topics such as multi-instance sharding or larger scale needs in winter 2019, I'll keep this thread updated as that guidance comes out.

Comment: Is there any progress on that? I would also be interested in scaling up to millions of concurrent users for a messenger like whats app.